# Undefined Array Key "image"

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

When i'm uploading image in my form it gives me Undefined Array Key "image" i'm giving it the EncType and right name but i don't know where is the problem

MySQL insert code

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
  if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
    $First_Name = $_POST['First_Name'];
    $Last_Name = $_POST['Last_Name'];
    $Email = $_POST['Email'];
    $Phone = $_POST['Phone'];
    $Password = sha1($_POST['Password']);
    $country = $_POST['country'];
     $image = $_POST['image'];

    if (isset($_POST['image'])) {
      $imageName = $_FILES['image']['name'];
      $imageType = $_FILES['image']['type'];
      $imageTmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
      move_uploaded_file($imageTmp, "images/", $image);
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(first_name,last_name,email,phone,password,country,image) VALUES ('$First_Name','$Last_Name','$Email','$Phone','$Password','$country','$image')";
  }
}
```

HTML Code

```
    <form method="POST" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      
           <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword2">image</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" name="image">
      </div>


    </form>
```

Comment: You use the correct `$_FILES['image']` in three lines, why did you use `$_POST['image']` before?

Comment: Problem is that you have `$_FILES['image']` instead of `$_POST['image']`.

Comment: So Should i remove it totally and it will be inserted from the FILES ?

Comment: @u_mulder Shouldn't that be the other way around? He _should_ use `$_FILES['image']` instead of `$_POST['image']`?

Comment: `move_uploaded_file()` takes _two_ parameters, not three

Comment: From PHP's [sha1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php) manual page: "_Warning It is not recommended to use this function to secure passwords, due to the fast nature of this hashing algorithm._" PHP has [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check my below code. it will be helpful for you.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
  if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
    $First_Name = $_POST['First_Name'];
    $Last_Name = $_POST['Last_Name'];
    $Email = $_POST['Email'];
    $Phone = $_POST['Phone'];
    $Password = sha1($_POST['Password']);
    $country = $_POST['country'];
    $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $folder = "images/".$image;


    if (isset($image)) {
      $imageName = $_FILES['image']['name'];
      $imageType = $_FILES['image']['type'];
      $imageTmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
      move_uploaded_file($imageTmp,$folder);

    }


$sql = "INSERT INTO users(first_name,last_name,email,phone,password,country,image) VALUES ('$First_Name','$Last_Name','$Email','$Phone','$Password','$country','$image')";`
      }
    }
```

Comment: no i am using   $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];

Comment: Yea its working thank You,But move_uploaded_file(); not working,The uploaded image saved to DB but not moved to the folder

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: please share you code

Comment: please read this article. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-upload-image-into-database-and-display-it-using-php/